# Merge multiple arrays from foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach, merge

I'm trying to get start and end dates from database, generate the range dates between start and end, create an array so I can disable them in datepicker. The problem is I'm getting multiple arrays. How can I merge them into one array?

That's what I have:

```
$datestartend = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM booking");
 while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($datestartend)){


$begin = new DateTime($result['tdate']);
$end = new DateTime($result['ldate']);

$interval = new DateInterval('P1D'); // 1 Day
$dateRange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);

 $range = [];
foreach ($dateRange as $date) {
    $range[] = $date->format('d-m-Y');
  }

echo json_encode($range);


 }
```

That's what I'm getting :

```
["11-11-2016","12-11-2016","13-11-2016","14-11-2016"]["11-02-2016","12-02-2016","13-02-2016","14-02-2016","15-02-2016","16-02-2016"]["22-08-2016","23-08-2016","24-08-2016","25-08-2016","26-08-2016","27-08-2016","28-08-2016","29-08-2016"]["21-10-2016","22-10-2016","23-10-2016","24-10-2016","25-10-2016","26-10-2016","27-10-2016","28-10-2016","29-10-2016","30-10-2016"]
```

That's what I want :

```
  ["11-11-2016","12-11-2016","13-11-2016","14-11-2016","11-02-2016","12-02-2016","13-02-2016","14-02-2016","15-02-2016","16-02-2016","22-08-2016","23-08-2016","24-08-2016","25-08-2016","26-08-2016","27-08-2016","28-08-2016","29-08-2016","21-10-2016","22-10-2016","23-10-2016","24-10-2016","25-10-2016","26-10-2016","27-10-2016","28-10-2016","29-10-2016","30-10-2016"]
```

Comment: did you try `array_push($range, $date->format('d-m-Y');` ?

Comment: thank you @JohnPangilinan   but i'm still getting the same results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this does not give you your wanted result because for every loop `$range = [];` will result in an empty array.
Then you fill the array with data and you echo the data `echo json_encode($range);`

On the next loop, the previous will happen again, that is why you see the multiple array notations.

It might help when you move the `$range = [];` array outside of the while loop and move this statement `echo json_encode($range);` to right after the while loop.

For example:

```
$datestartend = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM booking");
$range = [];
while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($datestartend)){
    $begin = new DateTime($result['tdate']);
    $end = new DateTime($result['ldate']);

    $interval = new DateInterval('P1D'); // 1 Day
    $dateRange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);

    foreach ($dateRange as $date) {
        $range[] = $date->format('d-m-Y');
    }
}

echo json_encode($range);
```